# how to change default landing page url

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to change my landing page url from [www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/) to [www.example.com/index/id](http://www.example.com/index/id)

I tried this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Redirect 301 / http://example.com/index/id

RewriteRule ^index/([^/]*)$ ?i=page.index&lang=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

But not works.

Please help me to fix this. Thank you..

Comment: Hey what happened tell me that you tried my code or not?

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite URL from `index.php` to `/index/id` you need to follow these two steps:

1. Create a new file into the root directory (so, in your `htdocs` folder only) with name of `.htaccess`
2. Copy the code below and paste it in the `.htaccess` file which will you created earlier.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/id index.php [L]
```

But there is a problem in it this code is only allow you to access `index.php` with another name if you want to redirect all traffic from `index.php` to new name I recommend you to do not make changes in `.htaccess` file just detect current `URL` in `index.php` file and redirect it as you want.

Example

```
<?
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if(parse_url($actual_link, PHP_URL_PATH) != "/index/id"){
header('Location: /index/id');
}
else{
// do nothing 
}
?>
```

Hope this will helpful for you, thank you